# Unzip files with node.js on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, zip, zlib, unzip

What options are there to handle unzipping **.zip** files from within a Node.js script on **Windows** (XP)?

I'm working with the latest (at present) [node.js v0.5.8](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.8/api/) Windows **node.exe**.

Suggestions welcome.

-P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node provides support for the ZLIB library which should allow you to decompress a zip file using gzip: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.8/api/zlib.html

Comment: Do you have some code examples? The documentation for the zlib is nil.

Comment: There is a little more documentation on the node-zlib project page on Github (https://github.com/kkaefer/node-zlib).

Comment: But it seems ZLib library is for zip streams (with or without) headers, not .zip archives...

Comment: node's zlib module isn't for archives. It's only for simple streams and buffers.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this [zip library](https://github.com/kriskowal/zip). It's very easy to install and use:

```
npm install zip
/* Only js dependencies, no local building needed */
```

*from `test.js`*

```
var z = require("zip");
var FS = require("fs");
var data = FS.readFileSync("test.zip")
var reader = z.Reader(data);
console.log(reader.toObject('utf-8'));
```

Provides also ways to iterate through the zip entries and getting data through `Buffer`s.

Answer (score 2):

[ADM-ZIP](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/wiki/ADM-ZIP-Introduction) is a pure JavaScript implementation for zip data compression for NodeJS.